# Parse Json file with SAS

Tags: json, parsing, sas

I'm trying for the first time to parse a Json File using SAS.
I found some scripts on the Internet and tried this CODE on SAS but could not make it work on my JSON datafile.

```
data parsed; 
infile data lrecl=32000 truncover scanover dlm=",";
input @'"driver_id":{' driver_id $255.
  @'"publication_site_id":{' publication_site_id $255.
  @'"confirmed_seat_count":{' confirmed_seat_count $255.
  @'"published_date":{' published_date $255.
  @'"trip_date":{' trip_date $255.
  @'"first_publication_date":{' first_publication_date $255.
  @'"profile_picture_added_date":{' profile_picture_added_date $255.;

driver_id=scan(driver_id, 1, '",');
published_date=scan(published_date, 1, '",');   
trip_date   =scan(trip_date, 1, '",');
publication_site_id=scan(publication_site_id, 1, '",');
confirmed_seat_count    =scan(confirmed_seat_count, 1, '",');
first_publication_date  =scan(first_publication_date, 1, '",');
profile_picture_added_date  =scan(profile_picture_added_date, 1, '",');
run;
```

Here is an overview of my Json file

```
{
"driver_id": {"0":11450650,"1":4705453,"2":18873210,"3":4892472,"4":47572650,"5":5242675}, 
"publication_site_id":{"0":1056,"1":1056,"2":1056,"3":5056,"4":1056,"5":1056},
"confirmed_seat_count":{"0":2.0,"1":0.0,"2":1.0,"3":0.0,"4":0.0,"5":0.0},
"published_date":{"0":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","1":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","2":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","3":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","4":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","5":"2015-06-16 00:00:00"},
"trip_date":{"0":"2015-06-21 19:00:00","1":"2015-06-21 12:00:00","2":"2015-06-19 17:00:00","3":"2015-06-17 15:30:23","4":"2015-06-21 15:00:00","5":"2015-06-21 17:00:00"},
"first_publication_date":{"0":"2015-01-10 00:00:00","1":"2014-01-25 00:00:00","2":"2014-12-22 00:00:00","3":"2014-10-22 00:00:00","4":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","5":"2014-11-20 00:00:00"},
"profile_picture_added_date":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":"2015-09-22 00:00:00","3":"2013-11-19 00:00:00","4":"2015-06-17 00:00:00","5":null}
}
```

I am very thankful for the help.

Regards 
SM

Comment: what version of SAS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This should help you on your way:

```
options noquotelenmax;
filename data temp lrecl=32000;

data _null_;
file data;
put '{
"driver_id": {"0":11450650,"1":4705453,"2":18873210,"3":4892472,"4":47572650,"5":5242675}, 
"publication_site_id":{"0":1056,"1":1056,"2":1056,"3":5056,"4":1056,"5":1056},
"confirmed_seat_count":{"0":2.0,"1":0.0,"2":1.0,"3":0.0,"4":0.0,"5":0.0},
"published_date":{"0":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","1":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","2":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","3":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","4":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","5":"2015-06-16 00:00:00"},
"trip_date":{"0":"2015-06-21 19:00:00","1":"2015-06-21 12:00:00","2":"2015-06-19 17:00:00","3":"2015-06-17 15:30:23","4":"2015-06-21 15:00:00","5":"2015-06-21 17:00:00"},
"first_publication_date":{"0":"2015-01-10 00:00:00","1":"2014-01-25 00:00:00","2":"2014-12-22 00:00:00","3":"2014-10-22 00:00:00","4":"2015-06-16 00:00:00","5":"2014-11-20 00:00:00"},
"profile_picture_added_date":{"0":null,"1":null,"2":"2015-09-22 00:00:00","3":"2013-11-19 00:00:00","4":"2015-06-17 00:00:00","5":null}
}';
run;

data parsed; 
infile data lrecl=32000 truncover scanover dlm='}' ;
input @'"driver_id": {' driver_id: $255.
  @'"publication_site_id":{' publication_site_id: $255.
  @'"confirmed_seat_count":{' confirmed_seat_count: $255.
  @'"published_date":{' published_date: $255.
  @'"trip_date":{' trip_date: $255.
  @'"first_publication_date":{' first_publication_date: $255.
  @'"profile_picture_added_date":{' profile_picture_added_date: $255.@@;
run;
```

I updated the delimeter (allowing you to keep the inner objects, which are themselves delimited), added the colon input modifier (allows you to read nonstandard values by saying "start reading at the next non-blank column") and finished with the @@ trailing column pointer to hold the record for outputting subsequent observations (chances are your json will arrive as one long stream).  Oh, I also added a space for `@'"driver_id": {'` - was this a typo?

I omitted the scan part, figured you have this bit under control!

Answer (score 1):

Not my finest work but it will give what you are after!. Need to reorganise columns and a bit of dq but your JSON will look as a SAS data set. I would recommend you to look at python `pandas` package. With `pandas` you would have sorted this with a single line of code.

```
data parsed; 
infile "/your_path/test.json" lrecl=32500 truncover scanover dlm="," firstobs=2;
input   @'"driver_id"' _driver_id $255.
        @'"publication_site_id"' _publication_site_id $255.
        @'"confirmed_seat_count"' _confirmed_seat_count $255.
        @'"published_date"' _published_date $255.
        @'"trip_date"' _trip_date $255.
        @'"first_publication_date"' _first_publication_date $255.
        @'"profile_picture_added_date"' _profile_picture_added_date $255.;
array v{*} _:;
do i=1 to dim(v);
    v[i]=prxchange('s/"\d+"//',-1,v[i]);
    v[i]=compress(v[i],'{}"');
    v[i]=substr(v[i],3); 
end;
run;

proc transpose data=parsed out=t_parsed ;
var _:;
run;

data want(drop=i);
set t_parsed;
array split(6) $50.;
do i=1 to dim(split);
 split[i] = scan(col1,i,',');
end;
run;

proc sort data=want; by _name_;run;

proc transpose data=want out=want_t(drop=_name_);
var split:;
id _name_;
run;
```